# P2P shell connection

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, firewall, p2p

Here is my problem. I have a computer (let's call it A) that is behind a firewall. I can't make port forwarding but the whole traffic is not blocked since I can use P2P transfer (specifically [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)).

On another network in a different location, I have the same thing for another computer B.

I can't modify the hardware of both computers.

*First question:* Is there a solution to open securely a shell from A to B (or B to A) using a P2P connection (I mean directly and bypassing firewalls)?

A and B are both running OpenSSH server.

*Second question:* Is there a way to make a P2P tunnel between A and B and transparently use ssh inside it?

I'm aware of P2P-VPN solution like **PeerVPN** or **Freelan** but I want A and B to remain on their respective networks.

Thanks for you answers!

Answer (score 0):

You did not clarify if the systems you want to be able to talk to each other are in the same physical location, but if they this may work.

One way that would require additional hardware is adding a second network card to each machine, and give them ip addresses in a different subnet and allow them to use that (private) network for file sharing or your ssh traffic.

Each system would remain on their respective networks for their public/current network cards.

Comment: My mistake, I edit the question.